# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, string, while-loop

```
name = raw_input("Welcome soldier. What is your name? ")
print('Ok,', name, ' we need your help.')
print("Do you want to help us? (Yes/No) ")
ans = raw_input().lower()

while True:
    ans = raw_input().lower()("This is one of those times when only Yes/No will do!" "\n"  "So what will it be? Yes? No?")

    ans = raw_input().lower()
    if ans() == 'yes' or 'no':
        break
    if ans == "yes":
        print ("Good!")
    elif ans == "no":
        print("I guess I was wrong about you..." '\n' "Game over.")
```

When I answer this happens;

First a blank line, then if I press the enter key again;

```
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    ans = raw_input().lower()("This is one of these times when only Yes/No will
do!" "\n" "So what will it be? Yes? No?")
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

What seams to be the problem?

P.S I searched the site but it seams that all the people with the same problem had far more advanced scripts and I did not understand anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first error is in the line

```
ans = raw_input().lower()("This is one of those times when only Yes/No will do!"
                          "\n"  "So what will it be? Yes? No?")
```

The result of `lower()` is a string, and parentheses after that mean that the object on the left (the string) gets called. Therefore, you get your error. You want

```
ans = raw_input("This is one of those times when only Yes/No will do!\n"
                "So what will it be? Yes? No?").lower()
```

Also,

```
if ans() == 'yes' or 'no':
```

does not what you expect. Again, `ans` is a string, and parentheses mean that the object on the left (the string) gets called. Therefore, you get your error.

Also, `or` is a logical operator. Even after removing the parentheses after `ans`, the code gets evaluated as:

```
if (ans == 'yes') or ('no'):
```

Since a non-empty string (`'no'`) evaluates to the [boolean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type) value True, this expression is always True. You simply want

```
if ans in ('yes', 'no'):
```

Additionally, you want to unindent the last lines. All in all, try:

```
name = raw_input("Welcome soldier. What is your name? ")
print('Ok, ' + name + ' we need your help.')
ans = raw_input("Do you want to help us? (Yes/No)").lower()
while True:
    if ans in ('yes', 'no'):
        break
    print("This is one of those times when only Yes/No will do!\n")
    ans = raw_input("So what will it be? Yes? No?").lower()

if ans == "yes":
    print("Good!")
elif ans == "no":
    print("I guess I was wrong about you..." '\n' "Game over.")
```

Comment: Update: Yea, I did it all, still stuck if I write rubbish more than once. 


Wow! That works! I can now run the loop forever no matter what kind of rubbish I write. 

However;
When I try to answer "yes" or "no" it still replies with; 
"This is one of these times when only Yes/No will do!"

Comment: After the last edit, this explains everything in my answer, so I'll delete mine. But the formatting is screwed up (after "All in all, try:" the code isn't a code block).

Comment: I tried it; Still gets me stuck in the while loop forever. 
Even if I answer "yes" straight away.

Comment: @AdrianLarsson Updated with a complete solution.

Comment: One more problem with the code that should be mentioned: It's using Python 3-style `print` functions, even though it's clearly Python 2 (given the `raw_input`). That means that, for example, `print('Ok', name, ' we need your help.')` is going to print `('Ok', 'Foo', ' we need your help.')`. (Also, the space before "we" is extraneous. And you don't need to, and shouldn't, put the `'\n'` in a separate string in the last line.)

Comment: Also, you could simplify this by doing `while ans not in ('yes', 'no'):` instead of `while True:` followed immediately by the equivalent `if` statement and `break`.

Comment: @abarnert `print` can be a function in Python 2 too, and even if it isn't, pretending that it is can simplify the mental model. Yeah, the code could be simplified further, but teaching `break` may actually have been the incentive behind that construct, so I'll leave it.

Comment: IGNORE. MY fault. Missed a thing. It is now working completely! 
THANK YOU all! Have a wonderful night! 

We are making progress! 
If I answer yes or no it skips the loop and I can proceed. 

However I still get stuck in the loop if I write rubbish and then tries to answer yes.

Comment: @phihag: No, it can't be a function in Python 2. And pretending that it is means you get broken output. Look at the example I gave. You _can_ get away with it by not using any commas, but unless you understand _why_ that works (which requires understanding one-item `tuple`s vs. simple parenthesized expressions) it's just going to mislead you into writing incorrect code later. It's also a sign that the OP may be mixing Py2 and Py3 tutorials, which is going to lead to all kinds of other confusion, and should be nipped in the bud.

Comment: @abarnert [Yes it can](http://ideone.com/emcJ36). The behavior you describe is unrelated to `print` as a function or statement; in Python 3, `print(1,2,3)` works as well.

Comment: @phihag: OK, yes, if you use a `__future__` statement. But neither the OP's code nor yours does that, and you wouldn't expect a newbie to guess that's the solution to his problem, would you? And the behavior is completely and totally related to `print` as a function or statement. As a function (Py3, or Py2 with the `__future__` statement), `print(1,2,3)` prints `1 2 3`; as a statement (Py2 normnally), it prints `(1, 2, 3)`. They both "work" in that they print something, but one is what you wanted to print, and the other is not.

Answer (score 4):

`TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` usually means you are using your `()` notation on a string, and Python tries to use that `str` object as a function. e.g. `"hello world"()`, or `"hello"("world")`

I think you meant to do :

```
ans = raw_input("This is one of those times...").lower()
```

**Another mistake:**

```
if ans() == 'yes' or 'no':
```

You have to check for both conditions individually,

Should be :

```
 if ans == 'yes' or ans == 'no':
        break
```

or more inline with what you wanted in the first place:

```
if ans in ('yes', 'no')
```

Comment: That helped me to run the loop once. 
If I answer "dhfjdshfkjdsj" again the program crashes and returns: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 13, in <module>
    if ans() == 'yes' or 'no':
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: @AdrianLarsson: That's a separate, but similar, problem. See phihag's answer for more details. (But I think you should accept BrenBarn's answer, because he solved your original problem, concisely, and before anyone else.)

Answer (score 3):

You need to do `raw_input("This is one of those times when only Yes/No will do!" "\n"  "So what will it be? Yes? No?").lower()`.

When you do `raw_input().lower()`, that already calls `raw_input()` and converts the result to lowercase.  By that time it's too late to try to pass your prompt string.